# Why doesn't this Update fail? is this intended behavior?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to understand why this update doesn't fail, and instead updates the table even though the sub-query contains an incorrect column name that doesn't exist in the table it is selecting from. If you run the sub-query by itself it returns a syntax error. Shouldn't the update fail and give an error? How is this being interpreted? a Co-worker suggested it may be interpreting this as a cross-apply, is that a possiblity?

```
Create table MyTable(column1 nvarchar(max), column2 nvarchar(max) , exclude nvarchar(max))
Create table MyTable2(c1 varchar)

INSERT INTO MyTable (column1, column2, exclude)
VALUES
    ('Fred', 'Smith',0),
    ('John', 'Smith',0),
    ('Michael', 'Smith',0),
    ('Robert', 'Smith',0);

INSERT INTO MyTable2
  ( c1)
VALUES
  ('x' ), 
  ('y'), 
  ('w'),
  ('n')

  Update [MyTable]  set [exclude] = 1 where [column1] in (select [column1] from [MyTable2])

  drop table MyTable
  drop table MyTable2
```

In the Sub-query for the update, Column1 does not exist. Despite this, the update runs on every row in the table. If you run the sub-query by itself, it returns a syntax error.

The expected behavior is that the update would fail, and the transaction would be rolled back

Comment: column1 is taken from MyTable in this case, use table prefixes to get error, like `select [MyTable2].[column1] from [MyTable2]`

Comment: You can say "select 7  from MyTable2".  7 is not a column of MyTable2.  This will generate a record for each record in MyTable2 each with one field with the value of the expression, 7.  In this case "select Column1 from MyTable2" works the same way.  The system will generate a record for each record of MyTable2, each with one field with the value of the expression Column1, which comes from the surrounding Select.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Expected.  [column1] is in scope in the subquery because it exists in the outer query.

Eg, for lots of queries like:

```
 Update [MyTable]  
 set [exclude] = 1 
 where exists (select * from [MyTable2] where c1 = [column1])
```

It's both legal and necessary to reference columns from the outer query in the subquery.

As @IłyaBursov points out, this is one of the many reasons to always prefix your column references with table aliases.

eg:

```
 Update [MyTable] t  
 set t.[exclude] = 1 
 where t.[column1] in (select t2.[column1] from [MyTable2] t2)
```